Root does not see KVM guests of non-super user
Why doesn't root know about a regular user's KVM guests?
user@Lin0011:~$ virsh list --all
 Id   Name         State
-----------------------------
 -    Lin0021   shut off

user@Lin0011:~$ 

root@Lin011# virsh list --all
 Id   Name   State
--------------------

root@Lin011# 

user@Lin0011:~$ virsh uri
qemu:///session

user@Lin0011:~$ 
user@Lin0011:~$ 
user@Lin0011:~$ env | grep VIR
user@Lin0011:~$ 

root@Lin011# virsh uri
qemu:///system

root@Lin011# 
root@Lin011# 
root@Lin011# env | grep VIR
root@Lin011# 




What's the output of virsh uri as both users? And env | grep VIR

Thank you for contributing. I've added the output.


Why doesn't root know about a regular user's KVM guests?

That is because the command virsh works in the context of the current user.
In order for arbitrary user (ex. root) to run the command in the context of another user we need to run the command in that users' context.
To make this possible pkexec command can help, if you're on Debian system first step is to install it as follows:
sudo apt install pkexec

If you're on some other distro which doesn't use apt then use your distro package manger to install pkexec instead of apt
Then if you're not root, login to root to test:
sudo -s

And execute the command in the context of the user named user
pkexec --user user virsh list --all

Should output virtual machines of the user named user
